# virtfs is too big!

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

I am using cPanel hosting. I rent 20GB and /home/virtfs is taking up nearly 10GB.

I read that using jailed shell accounts could be responsible for large virtfs file. Most of the user accounts have SFTP access using SSH identity key, but shell access is denied to all account (except root).

Any suggestions as to how to reduce the size of this file?

Answer (score 2):

Please see this: [Excessive disk usage with virtfs](https://serverfault.com/questions/652363/excessive-disk-usage-with-virtfs-cpanel/655688#655688)

VirtFS is used for jailed shell access on your various cpanel accounts.

The VirtFS doesn't actually count toward disk space since they're all basically symlinks.

Comment: Viniciusmunich, you linked to your answer to my related question, but I still have the same follow-up: Can you point me to documentation supporting your statement, "The VirtFS doesn't actually count toward disk space since they're all basically symlinks?" I have read this, but I can't find anything authoritative on that point.

Comment: [Here you go](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/VirtFS+-+Jailed+Shell) @EdCottrell... _This directory does not use any disk space. However, because it is a virtual mount point, some commands (for example, du) report that the directory uses disk space._

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring the size of `/home/virtfs`? It is indeed created for jailed shell logins, but those include SFTP logins. It contains a number of bind mounts, and so likely the disk usage you're seeing is logically elsewhere in the filesystem as well. In other words, that 10GB is probably real user data. The [cPanel docs](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/VirtFS) go into detail about VirtFS.

Comment: I checked the size by `du -chs /home/virtfs`. I will have a look at the cPanel link. Cheers.

Comment: FYI, `du` does not take into account hard links and bind mounts when calculating disk usage of a directory. So, while the total size of files inside `/home/virtfs` may sum to over 10GB, if you were to unmount `/home/virtfs`, I don't believe you'd see any less disk usage via `df`.

Answer (score 0):

try running below as root

/scripts/clear_orphaned_virtfs_mounts --clearall

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault - we prefer answers that explain a *why*, not just a how (see [this blog post](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/) for our reasoning). Please update your answer to provide a little more detail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are not using jailed shell, you (or some user) are PROBABLY using the CPanel's "Cron Jobs" option. If so, this option is responsible for generating the symlinks in /home/virtfs.

That said, I agree with @viniciusmunich the virtfs folder "used" space is counted twice, because these are symlinks of files already counted.

You can run `crontab -l -u username` to check if some user is running the cron job.

or `grep username /etc/passwd` to check for jailed shells.

BTW, do not delete the virtfs folder.

Answer (score 0):

According to cpanel documentation, we can not delete virtfs since if we enforce such commands like rm it will make user data deleted as well.

The main part of the question is its not taking your storage when it comes to storage number. It only creates hard links and storage numbers are false positive in this case.