# Excessive disk usage with virtfs

Tags: virtualhost, virtual-machines, filesystems, disk-space-utilization

I'm running a server with virtfs enabled, and seeing very high disk usage compared to the amount of data actually uploaded/created by each user. I am getting DISKWARN emails telling my that I am using nearly all of my available space, but I can't figure out why.

I ran `du -h / | grep "[0-9][MG]" | sort -n -r` to generate a list of the paths using the most space. This was the output:

```
68G    /
44G    /home
43G    /home/virtfs
11G    /home/virtfs/john
11G    /home/virtfs/paul
11G    /home/virtfs/george
11G    /home/virtfs/ringo
11G    /backup
5.3G   /usr
5.3G   /home/virtfs/john/usr
5.3G   /home/virtfs/paul/usr
5.3G   /home/virtfs/george/usr
5.3G   /home/virtfs/ringo/usr
5.2G   /var
5.2G   /home/virtfs/john/var
5.2G   /home/virtfs/paul/var
5.2G   /home/virtfs/george/var
5.2G   /home/virtfs/ringo/var
4.6G   /var/lib
4.6G   /home/virtfs/john/var/lib
4.6G   /home/virtfs/paul/var/lib
4.6G   /home/virtfs/george/var/lib
4.6G   /home/virtfs/ringo/var/lib
4.3G   /home/virtfs/paul/usr/local
4.2G   /usr/local
4.2G   /home/virtfs/john/usr/local
4.2G   /home/virtfs/george/usr/local
4.2G   /home/virtfs/ringo/usr/local
3.8G   /usr/local/cpanel
3.8G   /home/virtfs/john/usr/local/cpanel
3.8G   /home/virtfs/paul/usr/local/cpanel
3.8G   /home/virtfs/george/usr/local/cpanel
3.8G   /home/virtfs/ringo/usr/local/cpanel
3.0G   /var/lib/mysql.orig
3.0G   /home/virtfs/john/var/lib/mysql.orig
3.0G   /home/virtfs/paul/var/lib/mysql.orig
3.0G   /home/virtfs/george/var/lib/mysql.orig
3.0G   /home/virtfs/ringo/var/lib/mysql.orig
2.6G   /backup/weekly
2.2G   /backup/cpbackup
2.1G   /var/lib/mysql.orig/ringo_demo
2.1G   /home/virtfs/john/var/lib/mysql.orig/ringo_demo
2.1G   /home/virtfs/paul/var/lib/mysql.orig/ringo_demo
2.1G   /home/virtfs/george/var/lib/mysql.orig/ringo_demo
2.1G   /home/virtfs/ringo/var/lib/mysql.orig/ringo_demo
1.9G   /cpanel_backups
1.7G   /backup/monthly
1.6G   /var/lib/mysql
1.6G   /home/virtfs/john/var/lib/mysql
1.6G   /home/virtfs/paul/var/lib/mysql
1.6G   /home/virtfs/george/var/lib/mysql
1.6G   /home/virtfs/ringo/var/lib/mysql
1.2G   /usr/local/cpanel/bin
1.2G   /home/virtfs/john/usr/local/cpanel/bin
1.2G   /home/virtfs/paul/usr/local/cpanel/bin
1.2G   /home/virtfs/george/usr/local/cpanel/bin
1.2G   /home/virtfs/ringo/usr/local/cpanel/bin
1.1G   /root
```

(No, my users aren't actually all named for the Beatles...) It looks like nearly all of the disk usage is bogus, as in redundant references to system files like `/var/lib/mysql/...`.

None of my users is actually using as much space as reported. For example, none of them alone uses the full 1.6 GB reported above for `/var/lib/mysql`. And when I look at the disk usage for these accounts (in `/home/username`), it ranges from essentially zero to no more than 237 MB: nowhere near the 11 GB reported.

Why am I seeing redundant listings? What can I do about this?

**Edit:** By request, the following is the output of `df -h /`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       30G   25G  5.9G  81% /
```

**Please note: this question was closed because it mentioned cPanel. The question is *not* about cPanel; it's about virtfs and what tools I can use to determine my available disk space.** My server happens to run cPanel, but cPanel did not cause the issues above. I have found an answer that does not involve cPanel or cPanel tools, and I will happily post it here if the question is reopened. In the meantime, in the interest of being helpful, I have posted a version of that answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230122/54371).

Comment: Thanks for adding the `df -h /` ... being unfamilar with virtfs, I was wondering whether using virtfs itself causes one or more mount points (such as `/home/virtfs`, I'm speculating) to appear in the complete output of `df -h`.

Comment: This might be something that can be solved pretty quickly by the folks at Unix and Linux, [for example, this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52876/how-to-du-only-the-space-used-up-by-files-that-are-not-hardlinked-elsewhere).  Looking into the documentation on VirtFS, it looks like these might be hardlinks, not symlinks.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Thanks; I will try the suggestions in response to that post and will try posting my question over there if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

VirtFS is used for jailed shell access on your various cpanel accounts:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=363754

The VirtFS **doesn't actually count toward disk space** since they're all basically `symlinks`.

Do NOT delete this folder if jailed shells are mounted-- it will delete all of the files inside and could damage your server's functionality.

The used disk space reported on `/var/lib/mysql` is the total disk space used by all your cPanel accounts together.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to documentation supporting your statement, "The VirtFS doesn't actually count toward disk space since they're all basically symlinks?" I have read this, but I can't find anything authoritative on that point. Also, part of my question is this: how do I find out how much space is *actually* being used by the system plus all accounts (not just the MySQL storage)?